# How to find the mass spectrum of Cl3+?

Tags: mass-spectrometry

The setting of this problem is on the moon of Jupiter: Io.

> Given that chlorine exists in two isotopes: $\ce{{}^{35}_{17}Cl}~(33.3\%)$ and $\ce{{}^{37}_{17}Cl}~(66.7\%)$, what is the mass spectrum of $\ce{Cl3+}$?

What I know now is that there are 3 peaks in the mass spectrum of $\ce{Cl2+}$ because there are 3 possible combinations ($\ce{{}^{35}_{17}Cl}$ + $\ce{{}^{35}_{17}Cl}$ / $\ce{{}^{35}_{17}Cl}$ + $\ce{{}^{37}_{17}Cl}$ / $\ce{{}^{37}_{17}Cl}$ + $\ce{{}^{37}_{17}Cl}$). Therefore, there are 4 possible combinations and 4 peaks for $\ce{Cl3+}$.

However, I do not know how to make a mass spectrum graph with only this much information.

Comment: Consider Pascal's Triangle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, let's tackle this. First of all you worked out correctly that there are four different combinations, resulting in four different peaks. You have also given the probability for finding a $\ce{{}^{35}_{17}Cl}$ is $a=33.3\%\approx\frac13$ and the probability for finding a $\ce{{}^{37}_{17}Cl}$ is $b=66.7\%\approx\frac23$. Since you have three positions to fill, this will result in a binomial formula of third order, $(a+b)^3$. You can solve this easily with [Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), $(a+b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3$. You spectrum should therefore look like this table:
\begin{array}{lrr}\hline
   & \text{m/z} &\text{abundance}/\%\\\hline
\ce{[{}^{35}_{17}Cl_3]^{+}}                & 105   &  3.7  \\
\ce{[{}^{35}_{17}Cl_2{}^{37}_{17}Cl]^{+}}  & 107   & 22.2  \\
\ce{[{}^{35}_{17}Cl{}^{37}_{17}Cl_2]^{+}}  & 109   & 44.4  \\
\ce{[{}^{37}_{17}Cl_3]^{+}}                & 111   & 29.7  \\\hline
\end{array}

The following snowball diagram should further demonstrate this:
[image: snow ball diagramm]

Comment: I don't know mass spectro stuff but I guess in this line - "since you have three positions to fill, this will result in a binomial formula of third order" you probably meant "since you have **four** positions to fill..." (as there are four rows in your table)

Comment: @GaurangTandon No. Three atoms, three positions, three rows in the diagram, four different isotope combinations.

Comment: Aren't there **eight** possible combinations of isotopes? (as I see from the bottom row of your graph, and as is also easily observed from the fact there are three atoms in $\ce{Cl3+}$ each having two choices)

Comment: @GaurangTandon there are four different masses you can measure, because positions are irrelevant for that. There are six possible combinations, as there are symmetry equivalent ones.

Comment: "Six possible combinations" of what...?

Comment: @GaurangTandon Last row count all and substract the summery equivalent ones, you have 6 different ones left; four different sum formulas.